# windows azure caching: what does PREVIEW mean?

Tags: azure, azure-caching

It seems that Windows Azure Caching is still in Preview according to MSDN. And also some blogs say "Windows Azure Caching is not supported in production"

What does this mean? Does this mean that it is not possible to deploy Web Roles using Windows Azure Caching on Cloud? My gut feeling says it is not, but then I don't understand what the meaning of "being not supported in production" is.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deploy,but its not fully supported. So if something goes wrong, don't expect full support or any SLA rebates. It also means that its possible that something could change before it goes to full production availability.

Put simply, preview means "use at your own risk".